# MongoDB Data Transformation for UI display

Tags: mongodb, data-visualization, etl, data-warehouse

We've stumbled into a huge issue, which we need to figure out how to achieve in a right manner.

We are using MongoDB via Mongoose and dump a lot of different data.
We need to create a big aggregation from few collections based on certain inputs.

Creating an aggregation  function doesn't supply good performance times.

We need to find a technical solution, the correct one,
To actually create "ETL" but no a real ETL, to store a real time sample of the data, so UI layer could query it smoothly.

Let's say i have 5 collections, which i need a real time display of 3 fields of each, and "join" using aggregation won't supply a good enough performance wise solution.

We might need a mediator, we thought dumping data using etl to redshift but it doesn't feel like the right solution.

It seems like a common problem, but we don't seem to find the smooth and correct solution.

We don't mind deploying whatever needed.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It seems like a design issue. Did you consider to consolidate them into one collection if they are related collections so that you don’t need to join them like relational objects?

Comment: These are big amounts of data. That shouldn't be joined.